# Why have a non-generic IQueryable?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-expressions

1. Why is there a non-generic `IQueryable` when there's a generic one? Could you please provide a use for it?
2. Isn't the `ElementType` member of the non-generic `IQueryable` interface redundant for the same reason?

The two `IQueryable` interfaces were introduced well after generics had been introduced. So, having both the generic and non-generic version does not look like an evolutionary progression as is the case with `IEnumerable` and its generic version.

Surely, Microsoft must have had a strong reason to keep both of the interfaces?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56375/are-non-generic-collections-in-net-obsolete

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535017/iqueryable-vs-iqueryablet

Comment: Look at it as a shorthand for `IQueryable<object>` and no more

Comment: I read Matt Warren's series on building a LINQ provider and I am not sure what he means by the expression, "*dynamic query building scenarios*" when he says,  "The generic IQueryable<T> is the one you use most often in method signatures and the like. The non-generic IQueryable exist primarily to give you a weakly typed entry point primarily for dynamic query building scenarios."

Comment: I strongly disagree with @YoryeNathan comment. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose of this interface is to allow access to the `ElementType`, `Expression`, and `Provider` without needing to know the Generic Type.

This is a fairly common practice for Microsoft when writing Generic Types. `List<T>` inherits from `IList<T>` which inherits from `IList`.

In other words you want to expose any property that does not require the generic type in a non generic way. In the case of `IQueryable<T>` there is not properties exposed. However, the generic type `T` allows for strongly typed extension methods, that are found in `System.Linq.Queryable`.

Observe the following:

```
void Main()
{
    var lst = new List<string>();
    lst.Add("test1");
    lst.Add("test2");
    lst.Add("test3");

    IQueryable<string> q = lst.AsQueryable();

    PrintQueryInfo(  q.Where(x=>x.Contains('1')));

}

public void PrintQueryInfo(IQueryable q){
    Console.WriteLine(q.Expression.ToString());
}
```

Output:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].Where(x => x.Contains(1))
```

---

Its also worth noting that the above example could also be done with a generic method. But this is not always possible or practical.

```
public void PrintQueryInfo<T>(IQueryable<T> q){
    Console.WriteLine(q.Expression.ToString());
}
```